# Razor Components Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, razor-components

How would one use authentication SignInAsync as a call from a razor component.
It seems to throw some errors due to the context being in a late state of the pipeline.

Error when HttpContext.SignInAsync is called:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.)'    
InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
```

Here is the UserState.cs where the SignIn is implemented.

```
public class UserState
{

    readonly IHttpContextAccessor Context;

    public UserState(IHttpContextAccessor Context)
    {
        this.Context = Context;
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public ClaimsPrincipal User => Context.HttpContext.User;

    public bool IsLoggedIn => User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

    public void SignIn()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim> {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bob", ClaimValueTypes.String),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "Builder", ClaimValueTypes.String),
        };
        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

        Context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPrincipal,
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                IsPersistent = true,
                AllowRefresh = true
            }).Wait();
    }
}
```

method is called and injected as such:

```
@page "/"
@inject UserState User

@if (User.IsLoggedIn)
{
   <p>You are logged in</p>
} else {
  <p>You are NOT logged in</p>
}

<button onclick="@User.SignIn">Login</button>
```

Is there a way to signin get a success response and then refresh the page from the SignIn method.

Ive seen some similar implementation using MVC controllers. Is there no way of invoking a authentication request without involving mvc?

Comment: `<button onclick="@User.SignIn">Login</button>` should go inside the `else` right?

Comment: What does it mean `<button onclick="@User.SignIn">Login</button>`? It doesn't even compile

Comment: Using Razor Components .NET Core 3.0 (Visual Studio 2019)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem (Server-side Blazor).

Comment: No, I ended up having a Razor Page that the app redirects to when auth is needed. seems messing with the httpcontext mid request is a big no-no, but weird that blazor does not have a pre-request handler we can hook in too. leaving it open for some genius to answer tho'

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not a genius on the topic, but I'm fairly certain login in .razor components is impossible (unless maybe with Javascript??), something like .cshtml must be used.

Even the premade login you get when creating a new server side project with individual auth uses a *Login.cshtml*:

-> Right click the project -> Add -> New Scaffolded Item... -> AddIdentity -> Select all -> Add

[image]

Server side Blazor is basically sending html to the client, I can somewhat see how login/setting cookies is a problem, when you're actually working on the server (setting cookie with just html is impossible, to my knowledge?). But I haven't been able to find any explanation, I'm more or less guessing :(

Sidenote: I got weird double rendering when using .cshtml for login, solved by replacing the following line in *_Host.cshtml*

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered)
```

with

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server)
```

See:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18392
- [What's the difference between RenderMode.Server and RenderMode.ServerPrerendered in blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229732/whats-the-difference-between-rendermode-server-and-rendermode-serverprerendered)