# What's the difference between RenderMode.Server and RenderMode.ServerPrerendered in blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

What's the difference between

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Todo>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

and

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Todo>(RenderMode.Server))
```

I was looking into the documentation but couldn't really find something that explains the difference. and also don't really understand the code comments over the enum stating:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Renders a marker for a Blazor server-side application. This doesn't include any
    //     output from the component. When the user-agent starts, it uses this marker to
    //     bootstrap a blazor application.
    Server = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Renders the component into static HTML and includes a marker for a Blazor server-side
    //     application. When the user-agent starts, it uses this marker to bootstrap a blazor
    //     application.
    ServerPrerendered = 3
```

What is happening behind the scenes? 
And what are the Scenarios for using Server vs ServerPrerendered?

Comment: this is a good read on the subject: https://chrissainty.com/prerendering-a-client-side-blazor-application/

Comment: That link certainly is interesting but it's related to client-side Blazor applications, not server-side ones.

Comment: Be careful if using Microsoft Identity Client and Azure AD sign on. I switched my .Net 7 Blazor Server app to Server instead of ServerPrerendered and it broke my Azure Sign in.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Explained at [ASP.NET Core and Blazor updates in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/):

> - **Static Statically** render the component with the specified parameters.
> - **Server**   Render a marker where the component should be rendered interactively by the Blazor Server app.
> - **ServerPrerendered**    Statically prerender the component along with a marker to indicate the component should later be rendered interactively by the Blazor Server app.

This concept is related to **performance**. The fastest way to serve a page is to render page statically then send, and, the slowest way to serve a page is to serve an "interactive Blazor" server page (with a live virtual DOM synchronized via SignalR websockets).

`ServerPrerendered` is a trade-off: Blazor pre-renders page and sends it as a static page, then later the page becomes an interactive Blazor server app. This behavior is intended to serve pages quickly to search engines with time-based positioning.

Comment: What does that mean in plain english? Why would I not choose the fastest? What are the downsides? What is a "marker"? Aren't all components rendered interactively? Are static components rendered, sent and when there is a change it is rendered & sent again?

Comment: @Heinzlmaen Have you got any answer to these?

Comment: @Sofia I just played around with it a little, my (flawed) experiences: STATIC really is mostly html/css-like, when I click buttons all of the Blazor stuff doesn't do anything. No clue when to use this. SERVER seems to be what you'd expect, it just works. But I have a big site where it loads quite slowly. SERVERPRERENDERED quickly shows the static version, but is then reloaded like the SERVER part. This looks a lot faster, usually you don't notice the second load. In my site it flickers due to the long load, which is annoying. But I'm still using it, so it feels as if it would load quickly.

Comment: @Sofia By accident, I ran into an article where the STATIC mode is used (I only skimmed through it): https://andrewlock.net/dont-replace-your-view-components-with-razor-components/ As far as I understand, stuff like forms still work and he's using Blazor(=Razor Components) to "structure" his code.

Comment: @Sofia, could the "annoying flicker" be view components getting loaded twice? I noticed  the flicker as well with ServerPrerendered mode, and found it's due to the OnIntializedAsync() getting called twice, which was reloading page components unnecessarily (once during pre-render and then again when the client browser connects to the web server).

Comment: I am not using Microsoft Identity.  Here is what I observe.  OnInitializedAsync gets called twice but only on Index.razor, and more interesting... even on Index.razor it gets called only once after that first page load when the app starts (which is when it gets called twice.)  You really must be careful if OnInitializedAsync gets called twice.  Using render-mode="Server" instead of render-mode="ServerPrerendered" seems to prevent OnInitializedAsync from being called twice at any time.

Answer (score 24):

The main problem with **ServerPrerendered**  is that it loads twice ,so your data layer code is also executed twice. **Server** mode is just ok, may be a bit slower.

Comment: Another issue I've found is when I use Server (and im using WindowsIdentityManagement - Azure AD) I cannot redirect to the login page, it only works when I am on ServerPrerendered. BUT when I redirect using ServerPrerendered then it fails because as you say it loads twice, and tries to use the Authentication code twice, which then causes a:
"MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token."