# How to speed up Blazor performance?

Tags: nginx, blazor, signalr, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server application. It runs blazing fast in my local machine. But, when I deployed the app to a Linux Ubuntu 20.04 VPS with 2GB RAM, it runs horribly slow. For example - A button click takes one or more seconds to perform. Also, it **reloads every time** I navigate to a page.

I added Azure SignalR service, but it didn't improve any performance.

I have another asp.net app running side by side running on the same server and that app performs very well. But the blazor app is quite depressing.

How can I make my app run faster in production?

I have read the following articles to configure my project and deploy -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-6.0#linux-with-nginx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

I have measured the latency like this -

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@if (latency is null)
{
    <span>Calculating...</span>
}
else
{
    <span>@(latency.Value.TotalMilliseconds)ms</span>
}

@code {
    private DateTime startTime;
    private TimeSpan? latency;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var _ = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("toString");
            latency = DateTime.UtcNow - startTime;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And it returns like **327.616ms** or more most of the time.

Comment: Well, what does your `toString` function do?  What happens if you use a pure javascript button and run that function?  My guess is that your internet connection itself has high ping, in which case I'd recommend a WASM project instead of server-hosted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58231378/6146147 take a look at the prerendering option

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is it running on the same server. Also isn't 2GB for the server enough?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 toString does nothing. It just tests how much time it is taking to communicate between a simple console command. (I copied the code from a msft doc page)

Comment: Check the server allows websockets - check the browser dev tools for any errors/messages about negotiating protocols. check the browser dev tools network tab - do you have a "ws:" connection?