# OnInitializedAsync() is being called twice

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

For some reason when bringing up the page CampaignPage.razor, `OnInitializedAsync()` is being called twice.

In addition, the property `ReturnUrl` is null each time (should be the first time) and is null again when `HandleValidSubmitAsync()` is called.

The first time it hits it, this is the call stack:

```
    LouisHowe.web.dll!LouisHowe.web.Pages.Manager.CampaignPage.OnInitializedAsync() Line 143    C#
    [External Code] 
    LouisHowe.web.dll!LouisHowe.web.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync.AnonymousMethod__23_1() Line 40  C#
    [External Code]
```

And the second time, this is it:

```
    LouisHowe.web.dll!LouisHowe.web.Pages.Manager.CampaignPage.OnInitializedAsync() Line 143    C#
    [External Code]
```

In addition it's 5+ seconds between the two hits and there's very little the system is doing to initialize the page. It hits the database but that's Sql Server Express sitting on my computer doing nothing else.

This only happens for case of mode == read or update. And in that case, in `OnInitializedAsync()` it is calling the following code. So it's something in this code that is causing the issue.

Note that it calls the same dbContext to get `Countries.All()` for the case of mode == create and that does not have the problem. So it's something in the call to `Campaigns.FindByNames()` that's doing it - but how?

```
await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
{
    // 1. if no uniqueId then create mode (because what would we Read/Update)?
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UniqueId))
        ModeState = Mode.Create;
    else
    {
        // 2. if have a uniqueId then it can't be create.
        if (ModeState == Mode.Create)
            ModeState = Mode.Read;

        // 3. Read it in from the database.
        _campaign = await dbContext.Campaigns.FindByNames(string.Empty, 
                UniqueId, CampaignIncludes.All).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (_campaign == null)
        {
            _badUniqueId = true;
            ModeState = Mode.Read;
            return;
        }

        Model.Campaign = _campaign;
    }

    var list = new List<IOrganization>();
    list.AddRange(await dbContext.Countries.All().ToListAsync());
    list.Add(Country.Dashes);
    list.AddRange(await dbContext.States.All().ToListAsync());
    AllRegions = list;
}
```

And here's `FindByNames`

```
public static IQueryable<Campaign> FindByNames(this IQueryable<Campaign> source, string searchName, 
    string searchUniqueId, params Expression<Func<Campaign, object?>>[] includes)
{
    var query = source;
    if (searchName.Length != 0)
        query = query.Where(campaign => campaign.Name.Contains(searchName));
    if (searchUniqueId.Length != 0)
        query = query.Where(campaign => campaign.UniqueId.Contains(searchUniqueId));
    foreach (var include in includes)
        query = query.Include(include);
    return query.OrderBy(i => i.Name);
}
```

So, what would cause the long delay and the multiple calls?

---

So I did as @MrCakaShaunCurtis suggested and put a debug entering and leaving `OnInitializedAsync()` and here's what I get.

Only once case (mode == create):

```
enter OnInitializedAsync() CampaignPage Instance a69f0a2d-e36a-4297-b8a1-d8d9cd12bbd1
... 2 expected DB calls
leave OnInitializedAsync() CampaignPage Instance a69f0a2d-e36a-4297-b8a1-d8d9cd12bbd1
enter OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance a69f0a2d-e36a-4297-b8a1-d8d9cd12bbd1
leave OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance a69f0a2d-e36a-4297-b8a1-d8d9cd12bbd1
enter OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance a69f0a2d-e36a-4297-b8a1-d8d9cd12bbd1
leave OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance a69f0a2d-e36a-4297-b8a1-d8d9cd12bbd1
```

And for the calls twice case:

```
enter OnInitializedAsync() CampaignPage Instance 427cd0b9-bf07-41d7-924f-0355da16b441
... 4 (FindByNames query becomes 2 calls) expected DB calls
leave OnInitializedAsync() CampaignPage Instance 427cd0b9-bf07-41d7-924f-0355da16b441
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__userid_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName]
FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[Id] = @__userid_0
enter OnInitializedAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
... 4 calls again
leave OnInitializedAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.5\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
enter OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
leave OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
'LouisHowe.web.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\git\LouisHowe\LouisHowe.web\bin\Debug\net7.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
enter OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
leave OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
enter OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
leave OnAfterRenderAsync() CampaignPage Instance 2b5a7537-85cc-4bca-9b29-403f8cdba668
```

So it's calling the Identity DB to get the `AspNetUsers` user record. It generally does that before each call to `OnInitializedAsync()`, I assume to initialize the value in the `Task<AuthenticationState>` cascading parameter.

So it's re-initializing, before ever getting to `OnAfterRenderAsync()`.

I made the change @MarvinKlein suggested (2 places) - **that fixed it.** I now have:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using LouisHowe.web
@namespace LouisHowe.web.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Copyright (c) 2023 by David Thielen - ALL RIGHTS RESERVED -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <base href="~/"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dx-demo.css" asp-append-version="true">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dx-demo-pages.css" asp-append-version="true">

    <link href="LouisHowe.web.styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <script src="~/js/Interop.js"></script>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server"/>
</head>
<body>
    @{
        var initialTokenState = new Services.InitialApplicationState
            {
                XsrfToken = Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken,
                Cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"]
            };
    }

    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" param-InitialState="initialTokenState" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[And this is explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229732/whats-the-difference-between-rendermode-server-and-rendermode-serverprerendered) Which leads to another question [that I'll post separately.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452794/what-is-the-best-way-in-blazor-to-initialize-a-page-that-hits-the-db-to-initiali)

Comment: You are probably using RenderModer ServerPrerendered. Check within your _Host.cshtml file and change it to Server

Comment: @MarvinKlein Thank you!!! I've now put up [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76452794/what-is-the-best-way-in-blazor-to-initialize-a-page-that-hits-the-db-to-initiali) that asks when/where I should read in the data now that I've set it to `render-mode="Server"` and I would value your answer there. TIA

Comment: @MarvinKlein If you write your comment as an answer I'm happy to select it.

Comment: I don't know much about the `ServerPrerendered` mode to make a good answer about this topic. All I know is that I switch to `Server` in all my projects because it get's rid of this behaviour of loading the the data twice. 

I'm actually not sure what even the difference is between those two since I don't notice any noticable performance difference.

Comment: I changed it from "ServerPrerendered" to "Server" everywhere and this is still happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was provided by @MarvinKlein above in a comment.

In `_Host.cshtml` set `render-mode="Server"` (two locations) and then `OnInitializedAsync()` will only be called once.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had a redirect from an external service to my page, before the page was rendered, I had an initialization, and after first preview of the render, I got another initialization, which lead to `Exception` (since I was using a code to generate a token, that already was consumed).

As I didn't wanted to use `render-mode=Server` which may (or may not) have other impact, and since no other answer was existed, I solved it using another approach:

first of all, let me tell you that using the field `private bool _isInitialized` **won't work**, it just get reset on next initialization, and return `false` again.

For this, I used `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool isFirstRender)` instead of the `OnInitializedAsync()`.

```cs
@code{
    //My States
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if(!firstRender)
            return;

        // Code that shouldn't get called twice
        // Update states

        StateHasChanged(); // IF NOT USED, your updated version of states will not get rendered
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender); // Not required, it just returns the `Task.CompletedTask;`
    }
}
```

Note the last line is redundant and won't affect anything at all

```cs
// Implementation of `base.OnAfterRenderAsync`:
protected virtual Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    => Task.CompletedTask;
```

Answer (score -1):

Not possible. `OnInitialized{Async}` isn't called twice, your creating two instances of the component (or manually calling it).  You need to figure out why you're creating two instances.  Your code may be obvious to you, but to me it's pretty opaque without a lot of context.

To prove it, create a Unique ID for the component instance and log information to Output.  Here's how to do it with `Index`

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    public Guid Uid { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Initialized Component {this.GetType().Name} Instance {this.Uid.ToString()}");
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

When debugging do lots of debug writes to watch what happens and the sequence of events.  Break points often tell you nothing when you have async code running.  Humans are just toooo slow!

Comment: I added as you suggested (updated above). But @MarvinKlein comment above solved it - `render-mode="Server"` and it's now good. I'm assuming you always set that and it's best practices/your advice to do so?

Comment: This just became an interesting question again because [(DevEx now wants RenderMode.InteractiveServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759529/rendermode-interactiveserver-call-oninitializedasync-twice-how-can-i-avoid-a)

Comment: Even if you comment out all your code and outputs and simply have OnInitializedAsync(), it will STILL fire twice. So, indeed, it's possible. This function apparently fires twice as part of Blazor. I have no idea why. No code, no state changes, it just does it twice!

Comment: Just tried this example and, sure enough, OnInitializedAsync fires twice! 
Now we just need to figure out why (is this by design or another Blazor bug?)

Comment: @MC9000 - This question is pre Net8.  Render modes complicate what you see.  You may see `OnInitializedAsync` fire twice, but it's on two separate instances of the component - as stated in the answer.  Re-render and then render.  Check out many recent answers on this topic [go to David Thielan's profile, he's asked several questions on the topic], or ask a new question.  And it's by design {but designed to confuse!}

Comment: For example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78169012/blazor-interactiveserver-and-pre-rendering-when-is-oninitializedasync-called

Comment: I understand and tested on .Net7 . The "issue" is by design as I discovered as well, so set render-mode appropriately. MS needs to stop trying to "help" so much.