# Blazor server component property state is lost

Tags: server, blazor, state

In blazor server I have found references online that property state can be kept when the method OnInitializedAsync is called twice (ServerPrerendered)
Everytime when I try, currentCount has the default value which is 0 inside the OnInitialisedAsync.

```cs
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
@attribute [RenderModeServer]

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
** //first initialization is current count = 0
   //second initialization i would expect current count to be 1 and to be increased to 2 (but is again 0)**
        currentCount++;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

I am confused how can I simulate this?
If someone can share precise code which shows that the value of the property is kept for the second OnInitialized Call.

Comment: for why counter isn't 2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/76452262

Comment: [Polite] Why?  What state do you want to preserve that will have changed between pre-render and second render.  What's the Use Case? There's no point to your code at the moment other than it proves state isn't preserved.

Comment: If I understand your intent, you can just make `currentCount` static.

Comment: The reason behind this is learning, I want to make sure I understand how stuff work.
I know state management (cascading,service,container) can be used to save the state of that property but on the other hand as i described in the post i would like to know if this is also possible without state management (cascading,service,container).
A few days ago i've read that the component when is rerendered does not lose state.
In my case looks like it is loosing. I suppose what i've read was incorect.

Comment: Or as Rbee shows with the other article there are different objects created.
This i will not understand why afterall we use prerendering.
We render once on the server static component and then we render again interactive component to swap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not differentiating the component from it's state.

When the application pre-renders a page it creates a rendering context, creates a render which builds out the Render Tree [components and markup code], and renders the tree into a static page.  It has no events hooked up.  It passes this html page to the browser.

The Browser now establishes a SignalR connection to the server, which creates a Hub Session, and requests the page.  A render and render tree are created in the context of the Hub Session.  This is a totally different context to that used to create the pre-rendered page.

As you can see the components are created in two separate contexts. Components only exist [as live components] in the context of a Render instance.   You can't create them yourself and pass them around for processes to use.

If you want to share state between the two [I don't know why you would], you need to preserve the state from the first and load it into the second instance.

I say I don't know why you should, because no external interacts take place in the pre-render mode and therefore the state can only be mutated in a contrived way from within [which is what you are doing].

If you provide a valid Use Case I can explain further.