# RenderMode.InteractiveServer call OnInitializedAsync() twice - how can I avoid all that processing twice?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been using

```
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
```

However, the latest version of DevExpress requires:

```
<Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer"/>
```

Which I assume I can do as:

```
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

The new .NET 8 code sample appears to have no `_Host.cshtml` and defines all this a little different. But I can use the old `_Host.cshtml` + `App.razor` approach and don't need to conver to the new `Routes.razor` + `App.razor` - correct?

This all works fine for me - but asking to confirm that it should, as opposed to somehow I'm lucky and a change will break my code.

And my big question is as follows. When I switch to `ServerPrerendered`, it then calls `OnInitializedAsync()` twice. This is a big hit on the database on a lot of my pages. So it will take twice as long for the pages to render.

Is there any way to avoid this? Or are we stuck with slower pages if `ServerPrerendered` is used?

Comment: Yep, I saw the same issue, Initize is called twice. I think there is something fishy going on in .net 8. I had to manully disabled prerendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I can use the old _Host.cshtml + App.razor approach and don't need to convert to the new Routes.razor + App.razor - correct?

Yes

> When I switch to ServerPrerendered, it then calls OnInitializedAsync() twice. This is a big hit on the database on a lot of my pages. So it will take twice as long for the pages to render.

What render mode do you have set on App?  My guess is you aren't.

See this commentary of mine  which explains what's going on and how to detect which mode you are rendering various components in - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md.

Comment: I have in _Host.cshtml `<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />` to avoid the issues around `OnInitializedAsync()` being called twice (and `Inject` methods being null on the second call). But DevExpress may force my hand on this.

Comment: Maybe this is what we have to do, but I find it confounding that for something as well designed as Blazor, they now have this situation where `OnInitializedAsync()` is called twice so we hit our database twice. And on the second call cascading parameters are null. This feels fundamentally broken.

Comment: It only happens if you don't set the render mode globally in `App` or `_Host.cshtml`.  The main problem is not Render Mode *per see*, it's the template.  It leads you down the garden path without any govt. health warnings on choosing Auto and/or Per page/component.  Look at the questions on here.  Most are the result of people choosing the dog's breakfast (because they can).  I bet there's a few Microsoft people with headaches from banging their heads against the wall.  My guess is we'll see a big update come out soon with a modified template.

Comment: Auto and/or Per page/component should be labelled **For Experts Only**.

Comment: Here's hoping DevExpress provides a way to stick with Server (set in _Host.cshtml) for their components. They're working at present, but supposedly shouldn't be...

Answer (score 1):

Prerendering is enabled by default for interactive components now,if you want to disable prerendering for entire Blazor app in .net 8,you may try

```
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)/>
```

Here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering) related.

You could detect  if the componnet is frist rendered in OnInitializesAsync() method via HttpContext(it's not null during the frist rendering)

For .Net 8 razor components, you could access it as below:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }
```

.....

```
 bool firstRender = !(HttpContext is null);
```

Comment: My problem is that the DevExpress components require InteractiveServer. My question is how do I avoid calling the DB twice?

Comment: Sorry,@David Thielen,I missunderstood your requirement,you may try to cache the data received from db  during prerendering and  retrieve the state after prerendering,here 's a sample in this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering

Comment: I may be missing something but I don't see how that shows how to understand if my code is being called the first or second time. Nor does it even show an OnInitializesAsync() call. My worry is if I think I'm on the 1st call, and it's actually the 2nd, then I neve populate the page.

Comment: Hi,@David Thielen,I can't understand this line well,---My worry is if I think I'm on the 1st call, and it's actually the 2nd, then I neve populate the page--- do you think the second rendering would start before the first has done,and your page won't load the data

Comment: I was speaking to when your method is called. It should be called in `OnInitializedAsync()` the second time it is called. The problem is, when `OnInitializedAsync()` is called, how do I know if it's the 2nd time vs the user refreshed the page and it's the first time again.

Comment: Hi,@David Thielen,you could check if OnInitializedAsync() is call the first time or second time with httpcontext,I've updated my answer,hopes help

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Which leads to a follow-on question - [how do you get `CascadingParameter]` values in the second call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787526/how-do-i-get-a-cascadingparameter-in-the-second-call-to-oninitializedasync).

Comment: And thank you for wrestling this to a successful answer.