# How can I get the reference to a component in OnInitializedAsync() - InteractiveServer Mode

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Using the Blazor ver 6 & 7, I have _Host.cshtml set up as follows:

```
<head>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" param-InitialState="initialTokenState" />
</body>
```

And then with the above, I have a `PopupMessageBox` component that is in `MainLayout.razor` that can be displayed during the `OnInitializedAsync()` processing. For example, with their credentials they cannot view a page with the url parameters passed. So PopupMessageBox displays a message and when they click OK, redirects them.

This is set up as follows:

PopupMessageBox.razor:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed="true">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

<DxPopup @ref="MessageBoxPopup"
    <!-- lots of stuff -->
</DxPopup>
```

And then MainLayout.razor has:

```
<main class="@pageClass">
    <PopupMessageBox>
        <div class="main-content">
            @Body
        </div>
    </PopupMessageBox>
</main>
```

And finally in every razor.cs file where I need this, I have:

```
[CascadingParameter]
protected PopupMessageBox PopupMessageBox { get; set; } = default!;
```

The problem I face is, in version 8, with InteractiveServer mode, cascading parameters are not supported. And I've tested this - when `OnInitializedAsync()` is called the second time the parameter `PopupMessageBox` is null.

[There are examples about how to replace cascading parameters with services.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787526/how-do-i-get-a-cascadingparameter-in-the-second-call-to-oninitializedasync) And that works fine for the `AuthenticationStateTask`. But this is different. This is the `@ref` to a component that I need. And I often need it in `OnInitializedAsync()`.

And while calling `Task.Yield()` will often get the `PopupMessageBox` parameter populated - that is not guaranteed. Also, `OnAfterRenderAsync()` is not a safe place (nor is it appropriate) as it can be called before `OnInitializedAsync()` completes.

So what is a safe way to accomplish this?

Update - to answer MrC's question below, here is App.razor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorWebApp.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is Routes.razor:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>
```

There is no _Host.cshtml in version 8.

**Update:** And here we have MREs. Apologies, they do require the DevExpress Blazor libraries. [PopupExample_Ver_7.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3xcccgty2prb06z4xztts/PopupExample_Ver_7.zip?rlkey=ybq5pmr821z2bt2o44caxc9qo&dl=1) is a Blazor 7 example that works. This is what I am presently using. [PopupExample_Ver_8.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/kph83f5y9aohn3nwa8kg0/PopupExample_Ver_8.zip?rlkey=6e4ze89o90bi8xy0429g85x8j&dl=0) is the same thing using the new verison 8 `InteractiveServer`. It does not work.

Comment: What render mode do you have set in App.Razor on `Routes` and `HeadOutlet`?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - I just added it. I have `InteractiveServer`. And I haven't converted to this yet. I need to figure out how to have my PopupMessageBox. (And I also want to understand how to handle `OnInitializedAsync()` being called twice without reading the database twice.) TIA

Comment: Can you come up with [mre] project on Gitgub that demonstrates your issues?  It's hard talking stuff in a conceptual sense without some clear hard code reference points.  I'm currently rebuilding a Netcore 3.1 Blazor application built in the very early days, so am probably dealing with similar issues.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I just added to the question a version 7 MRE (works) and version 8 MRE (doesn't work). TIA

Comment: Hi,@David Thielen,Do you mean even if you've set InteractiveServer render mode for entire app,the cascading parameter keeps null? I tried with a InputText component to reproduce this issue  for  I can't use DevExpress right now,but it succeeded

Comment: See my second answer.  I've reworked your 8 MRE a little to remove the DevExpress dependency and added some console logging to see the render modes.  The code is in the referenced Repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you Net 8 Repo, this is what I've done.

My repo is here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/PopupMessageVer8

The first answer I gave holds good.

1. I've created a generic Bootstrap`MessageBox` to replace your `PopUpMessageBox` so there's no dependancy on DevExpress.  My trial version is long expired!

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="_messageBoxHandle" IsFixed="true">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="@this.CssClass" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @onclick="this.CloseAsync"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @_message
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="this.CloseAsync" >Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.CloseAsync">Understood</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .modal-dialog-show {
        display: block;
    }

    .modal-dialog-hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private bool _show;
    private string? _message;

    private string CssClass => _show ? "modal fade show modal-dialog-show" : "modal fade modal-dialog-hide";

    private TaskCompletionSource? _taskCompletionSource;

    private MessageBoxHandle _messageBoxHandle;

    public MessageBox()
    {
        _messageBoxHandle = new(this);
    }

    public Task ShowAsync(string message)
    {
        _message = message;
        _taskCompletionSource = new();
        _show = true;
        StateHasChanged();
        return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private Task CloseAsync()
    {
        _show = false;
        _taskCompletionSource?.SetResult();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

2. I've created a `MessageBoxHandle` to pass as the cascaded parameter.  It restricts functionality to what is necessary,

```cs
public readonly struct MessageBoxHandle
{
    private readonly MessageBox _messageBox;

    public MessageBoxHandle(MessageBox messageBox)
    {
        _messageBox = messageBox;
    }

    public Task ShowAsync(string message)
        => _messageBox.ShowAsync(message);

    // Add anything else you need to cascade here
}
```

3. I've added `@rendermode="InteractiveServer"` to the components in `App`

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs5.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PopupMessageVer8.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

4. I've added the following service to `Program` so we can detect the render mode.

```cs
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
        .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

    builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    var app = builder.Build();
```

5. Component to write the render mode to the console:

```cs
public class RenderStateLogger : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public object? Parent { get; set; }
    [Inject] private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor { get; set; } = default!;

    private string _renderState => !(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted)
    ? "PreRender"
    : "SSR";

    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        Console.WriteLine($"{this.Parent?.GetType().Name} lifecycle initiated. Render State: {_renderState}");
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}
```

6. Here's my Home:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<RenderStateLogger Parent="this" />

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.ShowMessage">Show MessageBox</button>
</div>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter] protected MessageBoxHandle MessageBoxHandle { get; set; } = default!;

    private async Task ShowMessage()
    {
        await this.MessageBoxHandle.ShowAsync("Be careful not to count over 10!!!");

    }
}
```

7. Add `<RenderStateLogger Parent="this" />` to Routes, MainLayout, Counter and Weather.

Run the application and navigate between the pages.  The console log is exactly as you would expect:  prerender on the first page loaded and then SPA navigation after that: Routes is running in the SPA.

```
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Home lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Home lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Counter lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Home lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
```

Now change `App` to:

```cs
<body>
    <Routes/>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
```

And run the application.  A very different story.  `Routes` and `MainLayout` are only statically rendered.  Every navigation is a server trip.  Double loading of `OnInitialized` every time!

```
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Home lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Counter lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Counter lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Counter lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Counter lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Home lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: PreRender
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
```

### Addressing Pre-Rendering

There are many ways to deal with pre-rendering.

The normal global method is:

```cs
    <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" />
```

With that set you get:

```
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Home lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Counter lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Home lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Counter lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Routes lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
MainLayout lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
Weather lifecycle initiated. Render State: SSR
```

But if you want to stop it within the application you can create a  simple `PreRenderSplash` component.

```cs
@if (_preRendering)
{
    @this.PreRenderContent
    return;
}

@this.ChildContent

@code {
    [Inject] private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? PreRenderContent { get; set; }

    private bool _preRendering => !(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted);
}
```

I've added it to `MainLayout`

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<RenderStateLogger Parent="this" />

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <MessageBox>
            <div class="top-row px-4">
                <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">About</a>
            </div>

            <article class="content px-4">
                <PreRenderingSplash>
                    @Body
                </PreRenderingSplash>
            </article>
        </MessageBox>
    </main>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
```

You could also add it to `Routes`:

```cs
<RenderStateLogger Parent="this" />
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <PreRenderingSplash>
            <ChildContent>
                <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
                <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
            </ChildContent>
            <PreRenderContent>
                @* Content Here *@
            </PreRenderContent>
        </PreRenderingSplash>
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question about double calls to `OnInitializedAsync`?  I saw some posts by you on the aspnetcore Github Repo.

Comment: Yes & no. I understand what's going on (I think). But I still don't understand **why** they decided to call `OnInitializedAsync` twice. Blazor is so well thought out and this strikes me as brain dead. So I'm clearly not getting the why somehow. (Or they truly did something stupid, but I find that very hard to believe.)

Comment: Basically because you're don't get much choice if you want to prerender.  It's two applications.  There's the need to encompass and integrate classic SSR and then there's `ComponentBase`.  If they could re-write `ComponentBase` today, I'm sure they would.  I could write you a `ComponentBase` like component that had a `PreRender{Async}` method that only gets called in pre-render mode, and the normal lifecycle events only get called in SPA render mode.  Think of the chaos if they did something similar to `ComponentBase` in Net9!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing:

1. `OnInitializedAsync` called twice
2. Cascades from the Layout being null on the second render.

Says to me the router and layout components are being statically rendered.

Why?

1. The cascades in the statically rendered `Layout` are in a different context to the SPA context running in the Blazor Server hub session.  The root of the render tree in the hub session is the current page i.e. whatever component is rendered in the `@Body` render fragment. Hence any [CascadingParameter] from above the root is `null`.
2. `OnInitializedAsync` called twice for every page says the router is running in static rendered mode.  Every navigation event is a trip to run the router statically on the server and thus you get a pre-render and then SPA render event every navigation event.

Yet your `App.razor` configuration contradicts that:

```cs
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

Should set the root of the rendertree for the SPA to `Routes`.  `Layout` should be rendered in the tree and any cascades available to child nodes.  The router should be running in the SPA hub session: one call to `OnInitializedAsync` .

What I see at the moment is a contradiction which you need to resolve by estabishing what rendermode your router and layout components are using.

Check out this repo - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.RenderState which provides a simple tool to do so.

Once we know the render mode, we'll know where to start looking.

Comment: I just added a version 8 MRE to the question. What I want (don't know if it's possible) is a way to have the `PopupMessageBox` using the version 8 `InteractiveServer` mode. I'd like to set that mode in App.razor, [but it's not clear if that is allowed.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53519)