# Usefulness of Blazor 8 prerendering

Tags: blazor, pre-rendering

Microsoft states *"Prerendering is the process of initially rendering page content on the server without enabling event handlers for rendered controls. The server outputs the HTML UI of the page as soon as possible in response to the initial request, which makes the app feel more responsive to users"*.

But there is no easy way to differentiate what is rendered during prerender from what is rendered in the final rendering.

As an example, take a page which fetches data from a database. It could be usefull to render only static content during prerendering and defer database access to final rendering. But there is no simple way to do it. Basically you end up doing the time expensive task (database access) two times, first while prerendering and then again in final rendering.

This has been [pointed out already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075628/why-are-blazor-lifecycle-methods-getting-executed-twice) an basically negate any speed or responsiveness advantage prerendering is supposed to bring.

Is prerendering currently an half baked functionality?
Any actual real use case for it?

Comment: It's not half-baked. You misunderstand what pre-rendering is about. As for `But there is no simple way to do it.` wrong, you can configure pre-rendering at the component level, easily ensuring that specific parts are pre-rendered. The SO question you link to doesn't say what you assume

Comment: Still no easy way to differentiate between pre and final rendering. Splitting a page over multiple components (some prerendered and some not) will do, but seems a lot of work for a marginal improvement.

Comment: All SPA frameworks, Angular, React, Blazor, Vue, work with components, not entire pages at a time.  As for `for a marginal improvement.` I wouldn't say that returning static HTML immediately instead of hitting databases and rendering everything every single time is marginal.

Answer (score 5):

> Usefulness of Blazor 8 prerendering

It all depends on your requirements.  Just because you don't see a need, doesn't mean that other's don't have one.

There are many, many questions on this very confusing topic.  I've referenced two that might be of interest below.

> Is prerendering currently an half baked functionality?

No, but it and *InteractiveAuto* need a government health warning.

[Personal View] You need to really understand what your doing before starting to use them in production.  They've been overhyped: everyone seems to jump straight in for the full a la carte option, get into trouble and blame the framework.

See:

[Blazor .Net 8 splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77653261/blazor-net-8-splash-screen)

[How can I get the reference to a component in OnInitializedAsync() - InteractiveServer Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77849362/how-can-i-get-the-reference-to-a-component-in-oninitializedasync-interactive/77856116?noredirect=1#comment137257171_77856116)

[How do I share state to be injected across components rendered in different render modes in blazor .net 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768044/how-do-i-share-state-to-be-injected-across-components-rendered-in-different-rend)

And a commentary of mine on the overall rendermode topic:

https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md

Answer (score 1):

Shaun, thank you for your help.

> Just because you don't see a need, doesn't mean that other's don't have one.

That's actually my point, I was asking for actual use cases where prerendering proves usefull.
Let me summarize what I've learned so far.

**RENDER MODE STATIC SERVER**

Prerendering does not apply.

**RENDER MODE INTERACTIVE SERVER**

Prerendering not triggered by interactive routing. This means in most applications it will be triggered only on the first access to the home page.

Inside OnInitialized{Async} you need to know if you are prerendering or not. This is not provided by the framework. Your Blazr.RenderState component does it.

So far the only valid use case seems a Splash Screen, like in your example, which can be done without prerendering anyhow.

Overall I don't see any advantage in using prerendering here.

**RENDER MODE INTERACTIVE WEB ASSEMBLY**

Prerendering does not apply.

**RENDER MODE INTERACTIVE AUTO**

This is where prerendering can be usefull, but it comes at a cost.

Like you say, government health warning here: you need to code your components, and all the services they depends on, in a location agnostic way, ie they must work both server side and client side.

How much this adds to the cost while improving user experience is application specific. Probabily worthwhile for a big application with a big budget, probably not for a small one.

Comment: Correct.  Pre-Rendering is a con trick.  The user thinks the page has loaded quicker than it really has.  It's the same for all SPA frameworks  The key is to design your landing page with no user interactivity and minimal slow loading content.  I'm redeveloping the first production Blazor App I wrote originally in Net3.1.  I'm sticking to straight Interactive Server.

Comment: And I believe that it's likely the further you get into building an *InteractiveAuto* application, the deeper the hole and the greater the complexity.  Watch out for the event horizon!

Comment: I agree. Like you, sticking with Interactive Server (and prerendering disabled) for my current app.