# Serilog duplicated logs

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 application with a Blazor frontend and I'm using Serilog logger.

Currently I have the following configuration for the loggers. As you can see I have three loggers, the first two loggers write to a database and the third one emits a slack message (using incoming webhooks).

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc =>
        lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty("Type", "A1"))
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
        connectionString: _connectionString,
        sinkOptions: sinkOptionsAudit,
        columnOptions: columnOptionsAudit))

   .WriteTo.Logger(lc =>
        lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty("Type", "B2"))
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
        connectionString: _connectionString,
        sinkOptions: sinkOptionsSession,
        columnOptions: columnOptionsSession))

    .WriteTo.Conditional(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error
        || e.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal,
        wt => wt.Slack(new SlackSinkOptions
        {
            WebHookUrl = "slackapi/messages",
            PropertyOverrideList = new HashSet<OverridableProperties>()
            {
                OverridableProperties.CustomIcon,
                OverridableProperties.CustomUserName
            }
        }))
        .CreateLogger();
```

The code above is loaded as an extension method in `program.cs`.

Then I created a static class called `LoggerHelper` with some methods, for instance let's take a look at the following. I omitted the complete method to simplify the code.

```
public static void EmitCriticalErrorSlack(string stackTrace)
{
    Log.Error($"{stackTrace}");
}
```

I invoke this method by using the command below

```
LoggerHelper.EmitCriticalErrorSlack("Hello Fatal error!");
```

In my `program.cs`, I loaded the logger configuration via an extension method.

This is working just fine, the issue is that I'm getting duplicated messages, or rows in case of the messages that are persisted to the database.

For example if I emit a critical error, it is sent to slack and after a couple of seconds another message arrives.

I've tried the following

- Making sure I don't have the logger configuration duplicated in appsettings. I don't have any configuration related to serilog there.
- Used `UseSerilogRequestLogging`, apparently this issue is related with net core middleware.

I'm using the following technologies

- NET Core 6.0
- Serilog sinks: Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer v6.3.0, Serilog.Sinks.Slack v2.2.2
- Serilog.Formatting.Compact v2.0.0
- Serilog.AspNetCore v8.0.0 --> this package provides a module for UseSerilogRequestLogging().

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be related to this https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-slack/issues/8

Comment: make sure the logger is not being configured multiple times.The static `LoggerHelper` class method `EmitCriticalErrorSlack` should not internally call another logger method. check `Log.Error($"{stackTrace}");` is the only place where the log is being written.try use Serilog's self-log feature to debug the logger itself. This can help identify if there's an internal issue with Serilog.`Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));`.Since you're using conditional logging for Slack messages, ensure that the condition is correct and that it's not overlapping with other conditions.

Comment: Yes, but LoggerHelper is just a wrapper, it is not calling one logger inside another. I tried selflog but it is working just fine.
The issue is when I trigger a serilog message inside an async method. This message is duplicated. If I trigger the serilog message from a synchronous method it is logging just once which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by changing the `render-mode` of the application to `Server`

Before

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

After

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

The main issue was not serilog itself, it was the double execution of the lifecycle methods provided by blazor. This post helped me a bit to understand: [What's the difference between RenderMode.Server and RenderMode.ServerPrerendered in blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229732/whats-the-difference-between-rendermode-server-and-rendermode-serverprerendered).

I debugged the code and some methods like `OnInitialized` a `OnInitializedAsync` are now executing just once.