# Blazor Server DOMContentLoaded not working in .js file

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Within my Blazor Server project I have a .js file with the following code:

***assets/js/main.js***

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Preloader
   */
  const preloader = document.querySelector('#preloader');
  if (preloader) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      preloader.remove();
    });
  }
});
```

Within my _Host.cshtml I have the following code:

***_Host.cshtml***

```
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Template Main JS File -->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    @* MUDBLAZOR *@
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

When I load my website, it looks like the website is loading twice (because it blinks once when loading). And the first time the preloader is removed, the second time it is not. At the end, the preloader is not removed.

Anyone any tips on how to solve this?

When I remove `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` from `_Host.cshtml`, my js script does work and the preloader is removed.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but since you are using the render mode `ServerPrerendered`, it is expected that the app loads twice (first statically pre-rendered, then the actual dynamic application). The `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` events are only called once because there is no *real* page load afterwards, only the content defined by your `<component type="typeof(App)">` is replaced. So your best bet would be to hook into a top level `OnInitialized` and call a JavaScript method to remove the preloader there. Or just do it in Blazor instead of JavaScript (would need to see the code for that).

Answer (score 0):

Your page is indeed loaded twice because of `ServerPrerendered`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67310528/436560

So you remove the preloader before the second load of the page, which leads to the behavior you experienced. You can use OnInitialized (see the life cycle here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and you can invoke a Javascript function from Blazor, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Now, in order to achieve your goals, you will need a Javascript function like this:

```
window.removePreloader = function() {
    let preloader = document.getElementById("preloader");
    if (preloader) preloader.remove();
}
```

and call this function from Blazor.